# How to enable compression for XFS file system on centos5.5?

Tags: centos, xfs

I am using file system type as "XFS" and i want to enable compression for XFS-file system. I surfed through the net but i couldnot found  related data. If anyone aware of the compression for XFS-file system please let me know..

Thanks Guys,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

XFS has no such facility as compression. See also [Wikipedia which mentions it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS) in the features box.

You would have to provide it on a higher level - or maybe at a lower one, if that exists (not that I am aware of, but one never knows)